# Does Microsoft Azure Container registry prorate the daily cost?

Tags: azure, azure-container-registry

I'm interested in storing container images in a Microsoft Azure Container Registry (ACR). However, I noticed that the daily cost for the "basic" tier of ACR costs $0.167 USD daily. I'm curious to know if this service has a pro-rated cost at a more granular interval than daily, as many other Microsoft Azure services do.

For example, if I create an ACR basic resource, and delete it 30 minutes later, will I billed for a full day?

Comment: ACI and ACR are two different things. Which do you mean?

Comment: @DerekGusoff Replaced ACI with ACR.

Comment: Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know it's already the whole means to calculate the price for Azure Container Registry in [Container Registry pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/container-registry/). Currently, no more granular interval than daily. For example, even if you use the basic SKU and only use one hour, it will still cost you the money which paid for one day. Actually, it's a storage and charges per day of storage used.